# Does Kendo UI Gantt chart support Planned Dates vs Actual Dates comparision?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

Does Kendo UI Gantt chart support Planned Dates vs Actual Dates comparision? Or is there any way to implement the same in Kendo Gantt Chart?

[image: Planned vs Actual comparison image]

**Edit**

Also would like to know whether it could show me progress line?

[image: Progress line image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific with the requirements? Maybe sharing a mockup?

Comment: In Gantt Charts there is usually provision to compare Planned dates of a task with the actual dates. So I wanted to know whether Kendo has this provision.

Comment: In this thread it is shown that it is Approved. So wanted to know if this feature is released or not.

https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1359996-support-for-actual-and-planned-comparison-in-gantt-chart

Comment: The way I can see it is doing a conditional format when the task is completely overdue render a different color. About the second question, Yes kendo Gantt chart has percentage of completed task. Please check the documentation here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt?_ga=2.192635299.846161861.1574252156-1272078643.1570527521

Comment: Planned vs Actual comparison cannot be attained by assigning different colors. Both planned dates and actual dates may totally differ. It should be shown as two bars one below the other against a single task.

I have used percentage of completion in my Gantt chart. My requirement is to show the progress line which is shown in red color in the second picture in the question. It will help me distinguish between the different tasks that are behind schedule and which are ahead of schedule.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI for jQuery Gantt does support the Planned vs Actual.
Check the demo below:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/planned-vs-actual